# Enumerate all running databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I'm writing a little Database administration program.
It works fine if you give the db, but not when you don't know which db is installed.

How can I enumerate all running databases?

e.g. Output of the program:

```
Port xy MS-SQL Server 2005
Port ab Postgre SQL Server 
Port cd MySQL Server
Port ef MS-SQL 2008 Express Server
Port gh Oracle Server
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your question...do you want the running DATABASES of a database server or do you you want the running database SERVERS in the network?

Comment: Do you have a list of which d should be on which port?  Or are you looking to step through the processes and identify them by the name of the executable?

Comment: the SERVERS, on the network and local
no i don't have a list

Stepping through the processes and identify them by the name of the executable would be an idea for localhost, but is there a way to get the port number ?

And what about NON-MS databases on the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For enumerating sql server instances (which is what i think you mean) you can find various examples on how to do this, which rely on the Sql Server Browser service, the other way is using SQLDMO.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx):

```
using System.Data.Sql;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // Retrieve the enumerator instance and then the data.
    SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance =
      SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
    System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();

    // Display the contents of the table.
    DisplayData(table);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }

  private static void DisplayData(System.Data.DataTable table)
  {
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
      foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("============================");
    }
  }
}
```

If your looking for more then this, i.e. being able to detect mysql/oracle ect. across the network then a more general tool such as [nmap](http://nmap.org/) may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to query all known database ports to find out if there is an instance running.  Where the database is running on a non-standard port, you will probably not be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can simply execute a procedure

```
exec SP_HelpDB
```

Note that this will only list all databases on the server that you have access to.

If you want all databases regardless of your access, you can do this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM master..sysdatabases
```

Comment: Similarly, PostgreSQL and MySQL both accept the marginally more standard "SHOW DATABASES".

But you need to have connected in the first place - catch 22?

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-hash of the previous poster's answer, but in VB.

You want to use the Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources method of the System.Data.Sql class.

```
Imports System.Data.Sql

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    ' Retrieve the enumerator instance and then the data.
    Dim instance As SqlDataSourceEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
    Dim table As System.Data.DataTable = instance.GetDataSources()

    ' Display the contents of the table.
    DisplayData(table)

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.")
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Private Sub DisplayData(ByVal table As DataTable)
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
      For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row(col))
      Next
      Console.WriteLine("============================")
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

I've got a database configuration dialog that uses this.  Works like a champ.