# How would one List the Databases in a SQL Server, not by query, but by c# call?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, enumerate

From this:
[Enumerate all running databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594315/enumerate-all-running-databases)

One can list the servers on the network, but once one selects one of those servers, how does one then list the DB's in that server, by using a similar method as above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Management Objects (SMO). First, you'd use the [SmoApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoapplication%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) class and one of its EnumAvailableSqlServers methods to find the server.

Once you've found the server you want, you'd create a [Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) instance, and then use its [Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.databases%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Oooh, I like this one even better :)

Answer (score 1):

Most interactions with a database server eventually translate to SQL. Even if they look like some other API in a higher level.
Look for the SQL to do this and just call it from C#

UPDATE:
From [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/12/sql-server-2005-list-all-the-database/)

```
----SQL SERVER 2005 System Procedures
EXEC sp_databases
EXEC sp_helpdb
----SQL 2000 Method still works in SQL Server 2005
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
SELECT name
FROM sys.sysdatabases
----SQL SERVER Un-Documented Procedure
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'PRINT ''?'''
```